# Хранимые процедуры и контроль версий

Tags: sql, sql-server, git

Допустим мы используем в своем проекте хранимые процедуры SQL. Мы их пишем прям в редакторе MS SQL Sterver Managament Studio.

Представим ситуацию: мы изменили код, далее мы поправили какую-то процедуру, или добавили новую. Здесь с кодом все понятно, мы его храним на сервере git и проследить его эволюцию не проблема, но что делать с хранимыми процедурами и как их эволюцию связывать с тем кодом для которого они написаны?

Comment: У нас как то без git была проблема с десятками объектов, куда высылался софт и при этом надо было менять структуру БД. Был сделан маленький патчер, который просто выполнял весь sql-код из файлов обновлений, в порядке их номеров. последний прогнанный на БД номер патча фиксировался в самой БД, таким образом показывая ее версию. В следующий раз патчер брал только файлы, который на БД еще не выполнялись. таким образом в git стоит хранить файлы с последней версией всех процедур и отдельные файлы патчей, доводящие структуру БД до нужного состояния

Comment: Для каждого релиза хранить скрипт с апдейтами БД + скрипты с текущим состояним объектов

Comment: Добавить хуг для git "pre-commit", который будет сбрасывать в отдельно заведенный файл все процедуры. Вот даже нашел вариант, но для MySQL: https://gist.github.com/mithereal/13d94f5a00f4741b6342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос был о том как хранить исходные коды базы данных то один из вариантов - это в вашем решении создать проект БД (http://prntscr.com/js8arv). Шаблон правда есть только для MS Sql, есть ли такой же для других СУБД для работы в VS - не знаю.
Заполнить проект из уже готовой базы можно через сравнение схем вот так (http://prntscr.com/js8d7v)
По факту вы загрузите себе полную схему вашей базы данных в виде набора файлов, каждый из которых представляет собой один обьект (таблица, процедура и т.д.).
Этот проект вы можете хранить в вашем решении. Все изменения будут фиксироваться в Git.
Дальнейшую разработку можно проводить в VS и потом также через сравнение схем обновлять базу, либо используя некий другой софт (тогда после изменений не забывайте также через сравнение схем обновлять проект в VS).
Но повторяю, это все хорошо, если база под вашим контролем. А если вы сдаете разработки заказчику, то нужно предусматривать механизм обновления базы при обновлении приложения (см. ответ про механизм обновления)

Comment: Хорошее решение спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Пользуйтесь и ни в чем себе не отказывайте :)

Answer (score 1):

Для MS SQL, как и для многих других РСУБД, можно за вечер написать утилиту, которая выгружает SQL-скрипт создания всех хранимок/представлений/триггеров в один большой или кучу отдельных файлов. Их можно коммитить в git вместе с исходниками.

Можно подойти к проблеме административно и просто обязать перед коммитом выгружать средствами той же Managament Studio скрипты для измененных процедур.

Чтобы не забыть, что именно выгружать, можно создать DML-триггеры, которые будут логировать что и когда изменял каждый программист.

Answer (score 0):

Если боевая база находится где-то не под вашим контролем, то придется разрабатывать механизм ее обновления. 
У меня в свое время был разработан следующий механизм для десктоп приложения:

1. При подключении к базе приложение сравнивает текущую версию базы (хранится в БД, обновляется скриптом обновления) с требуемой версией БД (хранится в приложении, обновляется разработчиком приложения при необходимости).
2. Если версия БД устарела, то приложение предлагает обновится.
3. Далее запускается утилита которая обновляет БД до нужной версии (по факту прогоняет скрипт обновления).

Comment: А процедуры вы пишите где в студии ли в менеджере? Какой-то контроль версий есть для них?