# Как принято хранить триггерные и вложенные процедуры СУБД?

Tags: база-данных, git, триггер

На данный момент накопилось довольно много кода на стороне сервера базы данных (вложенные и триггерные процедуры). Вследствие чего задался вопросом, принято ли хранить данный код в git и прочих системах контроля версий, или же нет? по крайней мере в клиентах postgresql не предусмотрена синхронизация с скв, а вручную заниматься этим было бы довольно странно. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

UPD: а так же, что на счёт кода для создания таблиц?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837346/194569

Comment: Любой код (кроме сгенерированного) должен хранится в системе контроля версий. Почему вы задались этим вопросом? В вашем случае он никогда не меняется?